# Running a program remotely with access privileges using ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu

I want to send a command from a ruby program that runs a program X remotely. After that I should be able to control the program X from the remote machine. Program X requires just text commands. There is no GUI involved. I read about Net::SSH, but I do not know how to make the server listen to the client (where the Net::SSH program is executed). The program fails with the following error:

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/net-ssh-2.9.1/lib/net/ssh/transport/session.rb:70:in `initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)

How do I make the server listen to the client? Also, is there a different way of doing this?

Comment: what Operating system is the remote server running? Your error message means the remote isn't listening for SSH connections on the port you tried, you would need to enable that first. but we we really need more information about what the remote end is.

Comment: The remote server is running on Ubuntu. I know that the remote host isn't listening. That's why I want to know how I can make it listen to the client.

Comment: if you need it to listen for SSH you just need to enable the ssh server, which can normally be done by running `sudo apt-get install openssh-server` and you can edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config if you want to change options (ports, etc..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a setup where the server of program X is a web server. Program X can be Rails app which will have API for your ruby program to use to control your program X.

If program X cannot be a rails app, you can write a Rails app that can link to your program X and also expose the API for your ruby program to communicates with. This way, you linked up your ruby program with your program X.

Net::SSH also can work. Your error is that the SSH gem cannot connect to your server. Make sure your server can work by SSH-ing in yourself via command prompt. Once all that basic configuration is sorted out, you should be able to use the gem to SSH in.

Comment: Yea, I was thinking of the second approach. Program X is not a rails app. So I will need a Rails app which can link to program X. Okay, so how do I make the server listen in Ubuntu? I am not very familiar with Ubuntu.
PS: Should I add ubuntu to the tags?

Comment: Yes you can add Ubuntu tag to the post. To make the server listen in Ubuntu, you have to configure your apache.